# Find groups in pandas DataFrame that satisfy multiple logical (boolean) conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns

```
Level Status     Id
0     Complete   a1
1     Start      c1
1     Complete   c1
2     Start      d1
2     Start      d2
2     Fail       d2
```

I want to filter data in which the for each level there should be only start and complete or start and fail given that the id for both are the same

```
Level Status     Id
1     Start      c1
1     Complete   c1
2     Start      d2
2     Fail       d2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy.transform('any')` to get groups that match the condition of Status having "Start" and Status also having one of {"Fail", "Complete"} using

```
status_has_start = df['Status'].eq('Start').groupby(df['Id']).transform('any')
status_has_complete_or_fail = (
    df['Status'].isin(['Complete', 'Fail']).groupby(df['Id']).transform('any'))

print (df.loc[status_has_start & status_has_complete_or_fail])

   Level    Status  Id
1      1     Start  c1
2      1  Complete  c1
4      2     Start  d2
5      2      Fail  d2
```

Where,

```
print (status_has_start)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: Status, dtype: bool

print (status_has_complete_or_fail)
 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: Status, dtype: bool
```

---

If you want a 1 liner on steroids, you can run

```
df.loc[pd.concat([df['Status'].eq('Start'), 
                  df['Status'].isin(['Complete', 'Fail'])], axis=1)
         .groupby([df['Level'], df['Id']])
         .transform('any')
         .all(axis=1)]

   Level    Status  Id
1      1     Start  c1
2      1  Complete  c1
4      2     Start  d2
5      2      Fail  d2
```

Comment: Nice answer but i guess we need to group using `Level` and `Id` :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thanks, that works too. Second option includes the additional grouper.

Comment: just a thought..consider if for the row at index `2` the value of level is `3` then the first option would not consider the `same` levels it filters the group based on only the same `Id` in that case there would be two seperate levels for id `c1`